# No such tuple on axis 0 error on iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, mdx, ireport, olap

How can I get measures value on iReport?

```
select 
 [Reg].[region].Children *
  {
    [measures].[mtot],
    [measures].[wtot]
  } on columns,
 [Title].[titlekhas].Children on rows 
from report1
```

There is my MDX query.

I have try add `fields` on iReport. 
When I add the `rows` and `cloumns` with this `expression` it works

```
<field name="Region" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Columns[Reg][ListRegion]]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="Title" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Rows[Title][Title]]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

But when i add measures with this `expression`

```
<field name="mtot" class="java.lang.Number">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Data([Reg].[region],?)]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

It return `No such tuple (...) on axis 0`

Am I doing wrong?
Every answer will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called `measures` with specific expression

```
<field name="Kuala Belait Man" class="java.lang.Number">
   <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Data(([Reg.hiReg].[region].[Kuala Belait], [Measures].[mtot]),?)]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```